# CSS horizontal alternate stripes with gradient on text

Tags: css

I've had a good look round and I haven't been able to work this out yet.

Does anyone know how to achieve the effect on the attached image of some text purely in CSS and not using any background images?

[image]

There are 2 pixel high alternating horizontal stripes. 1 stripe which is a solid colour, the other is a linear gradient.

Extra points, added respect, and the accepted answer will go to anyone who does it using something like an opacity gradient and only one colour so that you could change the entire look and feel of the text from the first image into the second image simply by changing the colour in one place.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like follow:

```css
body {
  background:#000;
  font-family:arial;
}

p{
  font-size: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right,transparent, var(--c,red)),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--c,red) 0,var(--c,red) 2px,transparent 2px,transparent 4px);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>
  example
</p>
<p style="--c:blue">
  example
</p>
```